# Why is mysqli_query failing - returning object when it should return resource

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried everything to find out why mysqli_query is failing.  Can anyone shed light as to what I'm doing wrong.  would be possible that I am not connecting to the dababase anymore??!!  Thank you in advance!

```
  function email_exists($email){
      $email = sanitize($email);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','secured_login');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
        die ($connect_error);
    }
    return (mysql_result(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

error

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in....
```

Alternative solution using mysqli_fetch_row();   <----- Isthe below alternative valid?

```
  function email_exists($email){
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','secured_login');
        if($db->connect_errno){
            $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
            die ($connect_error);
        }
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        while ($result= mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            return ($result);
        }           
    }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's simplest form, you should be looking at something similar to the following,

```
function email_exists($email){
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','secured_login');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
        die ($connect_error);
    }
    $query = $db->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
    return ($query->num_rows > 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Remember to sanitize your inputs, or even better, use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: good, but you should explain why instead of blindly offering a solution. Also, explaining about `mysqli_fetch_*` may be a good idea.

Comment: There is allot to learn about php.  Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up `mysql` with `mysqli`, why?

I presume it's a typo - but change `mysql_result` to `mysqli_result`

Comment: because I tried changing to that but I get the following error message ------Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Comment: Should I use mysqli_fetch_assoc?  any feedback?

Comment: That's because [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) is a class, not a function.